# Javascript logical operation (a === true || a === false)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I found this piece of code inside [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L2611). Why would we have this kind of check?

```
if (locale === true || locale === false) {
    strict = locale;
    locale = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used to ensure that `locale` is only used as the `strict` variable/parameter if it's actually a boolean value. Looking at that code, it looks like it's probably shuffling function parameters around based on whether optional ones have been specified. (In this case, `locale` would be the optional one prior to `strict`.)

Comment: I was wondering why didnot they used `typeof locale === 'boolean'`

Comment: @mumair: Matter of style, probably, or a micro-optimization (assuming the check above is faster than `typeof`, which I'm not assuming). (BTW: `typeof` is an operator, not a function; no need to put its operand in `()`.)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Nice. No great surprise there in that Chrome and IE11 both prefer the version used in Moment. But interesting that Firefox basically doesn't care which you use...

Comment: I was also surprised how fast Firefox is compared to Edge and Chrome, it does 3 times more operations / second on my system :o

Answer (score 3):

It checks if *locale* is exactly *true* or *false* instead of any other falsy (*undefined*, *null*, '', *NaN*, 0) or truthy values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your context. But, based on the code I think they wanna check the value of locale is a boolean.

```
if (locale === true || locale === false) {...}
```

So you can see they use triple equal to check (locale may be of another type).

Answer (score 0):

"==" means equal in value but not in type while, "===" means equal in value and type.

```
var x = 7;

x == "7" // returns true

x === "7" // returns false as x is not a string

x === 7 // returns true as they are both equal in value and type
```

For the code you provided, it looks like it is checking whether the value and type of locale is a boolean which is why is uses a triple equals comparison and also why it contains both true and false.